# In which cases is a waveform recording split into two recordings in MIMIC WDB 2v3?

Tags: mimic-iii

http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/ lists two cases where one waveform recording is split into two recordings:

- a patient was admitted more than once to any of the study ICUs during the study period
- gaps of an hour or more have been split into separate records

Are there other cases that cause a waveform recording to be split into two recordings in MIMIC WDB 2v3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, those are the only two reasons for a waveform record to be split into two segments. However the actual underlying reason why the gap occurred varies.